# CSS wrapping button with div

Tags: html, css

In my app in Ionic v1, I am trying to wrap the button with div so that I can get the area for clicking it bigger, but I can't get it to work:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>

      <div ng-if="canDeleteComment(comment)" class="remove-button-wrapper pull-right">
          <button class="remove" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)"></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the css for remove class:

```
.article .comments .item .remove {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 1.5rem;
    right: 1rem;
}

ionic.app.css:9895
.remove {
    display: block;
    background: url(../icons/remove.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have tried with setting the `.remove-button-wrapper` to `position:relative` and `display: inline-block` but that doesn't work since the wrapper is all the way to the left side, and the button on the right. How should I fix the css for wrapper to wrap the button so that I can have some padding around button to make the clickable area bigger?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is certainly setting your container to position: relative (or anything else), and then your button to position: absolute, and then set the top and left relative to the container.

However, you shall simply change the height and the width of your button to "make the clickable area bigger".

EDIT:

What about:

```
<div ng-if="canDeleteComment(comment)" class="remove-button-wrapper pull-right">
    <button class="remove" ng-click="deleteComment(comment)">Value</button>
</div>

<style>
    .remove-button-wrapper{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
</style>
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: No, I don't want to do that, because that will make my button bigger and I don't want that, I want to have the button the same size, but clickable area around it as well, since it is not a big button.

Comment: Fine, I didn't get that. So set the position of the container to anything (relative), and the the position of the button to absolute, and specify top and left variables. Alternatively, you can set display: flex to the container (with justify-content: center; align-items: center;) to center the button.

Comment: I tried that as well, but then the wrapper takes up the whole row. I can't seem to find a way to have a wrapper that would be only 10px wide around the button from all sides.

Comment: Just edited my answer (I used 50px instead of 10 and a coloured background for it to be more visible)